# Delegate Axis2 WSDL generation to the JAX-WS RI?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, apache-axis

I have a very simple JAX-WS + JAXB SOAP service that I am, by nature of my employment, forced to deploy via Axis2.

If I take my JAXB classes and my service class, and deploy them via the JAX-WS reference implementation baked into the JDK, e.g.

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:9090/MyService", new MyService());
}
```

The RI (2.2.4, JDK7) generates a beautiful, standards-compliant WSDL that can be consumed by pretty much any tool (soapUI, etc.).

---

If I take the very same classes and deploy them via a services.xml file in Axis2, e.g.

```
<service name="MyService" scope="soapsession" targetNamespace="http://com.service.my">
    <Description>My Service Endpoint</Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver" mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <!-- <parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter> -->
    <parameter locked="false" name="ServiceClass">com.service.my.MyService</parameter>
</service>
```

Axis2's WSDL generation takes over and generates **complete garbage** that's unusable by pretty much any tooling.

I know that I can uncomment the `<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>` line in my services.xml and provide a static WSDL, but doing so forces me to keep the WSDL updated manually in the future, which I would prefer to avoid.

**Is there any way to deploy my service via Axis2 and have the WSDL generated, but circumvent Axis2's abysmal WSDL generation and delegate that to the JAX-WS RI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is not possible without modifying or hooking into Axis2's implementation, which obviously creates a maintenance problem later on.  As such, I guess I will just live with the crappy WSDLs that Axis2 generates.